# check if table is empty, if not empty update field sqllite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning sqllite for android, but I cannot understand.
I create database handler like this :

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookMyFitManager";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_LANGUAGE = "language";
    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String LANGUAGE_ID = "languageid";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LANGUAGE + "("
                + LANGUAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+ ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LANGUAGE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    void addLanguage(String language) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LANGUAGE_ID, language);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LANGUAGE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public int updateLanguage(String language) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LANGUAGE_ID, language);

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_LANGUAGE, values, LANGUAGE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(language) });
    }
    public boolean checkForTables(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +TABLE_LANGUAGE, null);

        if(cursor != null){

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int count = cursor.getInt(0);

            if(count > 0){
                return true;
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I put this on activity :

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
db.checkForTables();
```

But did not work.
The basic is I create a toggle button, when it is on it sends 1 as parameter, when it is off it sends 2 as parameter. After that I want to send the parameter to database as language_id (string language on above code addlanguage or updatelanguage).

How to check if table is empty? And How to update if table not empty? (from activity).

How to call LANGUAGE_ID in another activity? Use code below ?

```
db.openDataBase();
final String lang_id = db.getLanguageid();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside checkForTables() it must be
    `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();`